# Bind multiple variables from a list to one combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I just started learning WPF and C#.

Consider:

```csharp
private void TransferAccountButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Client> allClients = Client.JsonToList();
    TransferStackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    TransferNameCombobox.DataContext = allClients;
    TransferNameCombobox.DisplayMemberPath = "surname";
}
```

I need to display multiple fields in a combo box. Something like

```csharp
TransferNameCombobox.DisplayMemberPath = "surname" + " " + "name" + " " + "patronymic";
```

If I do this it will show empty fields.
I understand that "surname" is not a string, but I don't understand how to do it.

In XAML, I only have:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="TransferNameCombobox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `TransferNameCombobox.DataContext = allClients;` make it `TransferNameCombobox.ItemsSource = allClients;` and delete `TransferNameCombobox.DisplayMemberPath = "surname";`

And then in the xaml, use this `MultiBinding` structure:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="TransferNameCombobox">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}, {1}, {2}">
                                <Binding Path="surname"/>
                                <Binding Path="name"/>
                                <Binding Path="patronymic"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```